# Use value from subquery in main query

Tags: mysql

I'm barely learning MySQL and find it exceedingly hard to wrap my head around writing queries since variables arn't used and passed around like when writing e.g. JavaScript.

I'm trying to run a "foreach" loop over items in a table and then return a table that includes the results of a calculation that happens in a subquery.

In the scenario there are two tables in a relational database:

`products` with the columns `product_id` and `stock`.

`line_items` with the columns `product_id` and `quantity`.

Several line items might appear for one `product_id` (there are more fields and more complexity in the query, but this breaks down the problem quite well, I think).

The objective is to:

For each `product.product_id`:

1. sum up `line_items.quantity` for items where `product.product_id = line_items.product_id`
2. if `product.stock - sum > 0` then return a row with `product.product_id, product.stock - sum`.

The query I have looks like:

```
SELECT products.product_id, products.stock
    FROM products
        WHERE
        products.stock - (
        SELECT SUM(line_items.quantity)
            FROM line_items
            WHERE line_items.product_id = products.product_id
        ) > 0
```

The problem is, I can't seem to figure out how I can do the logical check (`x > 0 ?`) and if it is true, use that value in the main query. Eventually producing something like this:

`SELECT products.product_id, (products.stock - sum)
...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just move your subquery into the main `SELECT`, and then use a `HAVING` clause to filter the values (you can't use aliases in `WHERE` clauses so you would have to write the whole expression again as you did in your original query):

```
SELECT products.product_id, 
       products.stock - (SELECT SUM(line_items.quantity)
                         FROM line_items
                         WHERE line_items.product_id = products.product_id
                        ) AS stock_on_hand
FROM products
HAVING stock_on_hand > 0
```

It's probably more efficient to write this as a `JOIN` query:

```
SELECT p.product_id, 
       p.stock - l.quantity AS stock_on_hand
FROM products p
JOIN (SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity) AS quantity
      FROM line_items
      GROUP BY product_id) l ON l.product_id = p.product_id
HAVING stock_on_hand > 0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ac4a081f40aaff7d89c49ed6307c533b)

Comment: Thanks so much! That makes a lot of sense!